# Scala method call parameters with colon

Tags: scala

```
final def apply(block: => Result): Action[AnyContent] =
    apply(BodyParsers.utils.ignore(AnyContentAsEmpty: AnyContent))(_ => block)
```

Does Anybody know what does this `AnyContentAsEmpty: AnyContent` mean ? Particularly `: AnyContent` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does Anybody know what does this `AnyContentAsEmpty: AnyContent` mean ?

It is a [*Typed Expression*](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#typed-expressions).

> Particularly `: AnyContent` ?

This is a [*Type Ascription*](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#expressions), which is used to ascribe a type to an expression, thus making the expression a typed expression.

Normally, Scala computes the types of expressions without your help, but you can ascribe a specific type to an expression, if you don't like the one that Scala computes.

For example, for the expression

```
42
```

Scala computes the type `Int`. You could also write

```
42: Int
```

instead, and you would get the same result. If you *don't* want `42` to be typed as `Int`, you can ascribe a different type to it, e.g.:

```
42: Long
```

Now, the expression has type `Long` instead of `Int`. If you were to assign it to a `val`, for example, and don't provide a type for the `val`, Scala would infer type `Long`:

```
val a       = 1       // 1 has type Int, therefore Scala infers type Int for a
val b: Long = 1       // b is typed as Long, therefore Scala converts 1 to a Long
val c       = 1: Long // 1 is typed as Long, therefore Scala infers type Long for c
```

You can use this to guide Scala to infer a more sensible type, or to pick a particular overload.

Answer (score 1):

An expression of the form `expr: Type` simply means the value of `expr`, but with the type `Type`. This is useful in guiding type inference. That is, the expression

```
AnyContentAsEmpty
```

has type

```
AnyContentAsEmpty.type
```

while

```
AnyContentAsEmpty: AnyContent
```

has type

```
AnyContent
```

I'm not sure why it's being used here, but maybe you can remove the `: AnyContent` and see what happens.

This syntax, called a *type ascription*, has two other uses: Implicit conversions and varargs. Also, note how it's similar to a variable declaration/`case` statement (`val x: Any = ???`/`case x: String => ???`).

```
class Base
class Extn
implicit def Base2Extn(b: Base) = new Extn
val x = new Base // x has type Base
val y = new Base: Extn // y is Base2Extn(new Base), with type Extn

def f(args: Any*): Unit = args match {
  // `tail: _*` is like saying "use tail as a bunch of arguments instead of just one"
  // Bit of a stretch but I think that's why the syntax was chosen
  case head +: tail => { println(head); f(tail: _*) }
  case _ => ()
}
```